# mysql performance index

Tags: mysql, indexing

i'll never understand the correct usage of mysql index. In every post and documentation I've read, they are just talking about simple index.
I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(sid),f_partner,COUNT(DISTINCT(cid)) FROM sal_forwarding WHERE 
forwardDate BETWEEN "2011-06-01" AND "2011-06-30" GROUP BY f_partner
```

It needs 2minutes to read the data. :(
The table has 1.4million Datarows.

Here ist the explain result:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  sal_forwarding  index   forwardDate,forwardDate_2,forwardDate_3 f_partner   25  (NULL)  1416282 Using where
```

My index is(f_partner,forwardDate).
What is the correct solution to improve the performance?

```
f_partner = varchar(20)
forwardDate = Date
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: [This part of the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html) answered all my questions related to MySQL indexes.

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com - an entire site devoted to indexing, not only simple cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index should be (forwardDate, f_partner) - first satisfy where clause, then group_by